# cypher neo4j iterate over graph starting with node and ending with node

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I have a graph at neo4j that looks like this :
(1)->(2)->(3)->(4)->(5)->(6)
I want to start iterating start from the third node to the fifth node and get them 
how can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one can probably answered many ways but here is one example.

Consider this test data...

```
create (t1:Test {name:'1'})
create (t2:Test {name:'2'})
create (t3:Test {name:'3'})
create (t4:Test {name:'4'})
create (t5:Test {name:'5'})
create (t6:Test {name:'6'})
create t1-[:JOINED_TO]->t2
create t2-[:JOINED_TO]->t3
create t3-[:JOINED_TO]->t4
create t4-[:JOINED_TO]->t5
create t5-[:JOINED_TO]->t6
```

Then you can return the 3rd to 5th nodes with the following query...

```
match p=(:Test {name:'3'})-[:JOINED_TO*]->(:Test {name:'5'})
return p
```

Comment: np.  i would be wary of the JOINED_TO* in the example above.  Not a problem in this little test data set bt if you had a larger data set you would likely want to put some constraints around it. You could for example, do this instead `p=(:Test {name:'3'})-[:JOINED_TO*2]->(:Test)`.